# Creating git post-merge hooks and using them in Git Tower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rails-migrations, git-tower

We use Git Tower to manage our git repositories, and we want to set up the ability to run an automatic `rake db:migrate` whenever we pull down a new update. I've modified the post-merge git hook to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

If I run this from the command line, it works just fine. However, if I try to run a git pull within Tower itself, I get the following error:

`/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.1.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:90:in 'materialize': Could not find sass-3.2.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

Does anyone have any experience getting Tower to run automatic migrations on git pull?

Answer (score 0):

put this in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

then in .git/hook/post-merge file:

```
exec <path/to/script/based/on/repo/directory>/<script_name> &
```

you need the & at the end of the line.  the hooks script has to return immediately or git gets unhappy.

sb

Comment: I don't see how having the script return immediately is going to cause rake to stop throwing an exception from missing a sass gem.